# Installing godaddy ssl certificate to server : getting this below error when i restart service nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key") failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)

```
#HTTPS server configuration
 server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/mydomain.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/mydomain.key;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name mydomain; 

        location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }
   }
```

Comment: There is no gap in the crt file OR no unwanted letters or anything. I read many Q&A sections and could understand how crt works. But still couldn't figure it out. 
I'm new to nginx server problems and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the first line of the file `/etc/nginx/mydomain.key`?

Comment: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
This is the first line. Thanks for your reply @RichardSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I hit this exact problem and solved it too.
Solution was to open the private key file in Notepad++ and change encoding to ANSI and then upload to server and use it.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters this, @aCid was right. The problem for me was the encoding on the `.key` file.

I used `GoDaddy` and had them generate the private key for me (then downloaded it). It turns out that it was encoded as `UTF-8`. This doesn't work for `NGINX`. You needed it encoded in ASCII.

Since this was already on my server and I was accessing it via SSH, I simply:

1. opened the original key file (encoded in `UTF-8`)
2. Copied the contents.
3. Created a new key file (`vi newfile.key`).
4. Pasted the contents from #2 into the new file.
5. Moved the new key file into the place of the old one.

After that everything worked fine.